# Nonblocking sockets even if not explicitly setting them as nonblocking

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, blocking, nonblocking

I have a TCP application written in C++, where a client and a server exchange data. I've istantiated a socket, believing that it would have been blocking by default; on the contrary, after server waits for a client, I have that client calls the recv function without waiting for data. This is the code in which I inizialize the socket fr the client.

```
int TCPreceiver::initialize(char* address, int port)
{
    sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    cout << "Socket: " << sock << endl;
    sockaddr_in target;
    target.sin_family = AF_INET;
    target.sin_port = htons (port);
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address);

    int fails=0;
    while (connect(sock, (sockaddr*) &target, sizeof(target)) == -1)
    {
        fails++;
        if (fails==10)
        {
            close(sock);
            cout << "Error with connection to the server, try again"<< endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    cout << "Client connected (control channel)" << endl;

    unsigned char text[10]; //Request message
    //fill text[]
    if(send(sock, (char*)text, 10, 0)==-1)
    {
            printf("send() failed with error code : %d" , -1);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried adding this code:

```
int opts;
opts = fcntl(sock,F_GETFL);
if (opts < 0) {
    perror("fcntl(F_GETFL)");
    exit(0);
}
opts = (opts & (~O_NONBLOCK));
if (fcntl(sock,F_SETFL,opts) < 0) {
    perror("fcntl(F_SETFL)");
    exit(0);
}
```

but it still doesn't work, and if I call the recv(), the application doesn't block (and recv() always returns 0). Here is the function where I call the recv():

```
void TCPreceiver::receive(char* text, int& dim)
{
    int ret;

    ret = recv(sock, text, dim, 0);
    dim=ret;
    if(ret == -1){
        printf("recv() failed with error (%d)\n", ret);
        //system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

recv() returning zero indicates either (1) you passed a zero length, which is just a programming error which I won't discuss further here, or (2) end of stream. The peer has close the connection. This isn't a non-blocking situation, this is the end of the connection. You must close the socket and stop using it. It will never return anything. It zero ever again.

See the *man* pages.

Comment: **Problem solved**: in the recv() I passed argument dim, which is 0. @EJP, thank you for addressing me on the right source of the problem.